# how to use getSharedPreferences in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I saw a video on YouTube that creates a quiz app for Android. I try to do this but inside a Fragment. He used getSharedPreferences somewhere and my problem is I can't use it on a fragment.

Here's the part where im getting the error. I hope someone can help me because I really need it to work. Its my school project.

FragmentQuiz.java

```
 private void updateHighscore(int highscoreNew) {
    highscore = highscoreNew;
    textViewHighscore.setText("Highscore: " + highscore);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(KEY_HIGHSCORE, highscore);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)?

Edit:
Possible duplicate of [Android SharedPreferences in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741270/android-sharedpreferences-in-fragment)

Comment: I tried it and it works, thank you mate, you just saved me from a failing grade :>

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a solution to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46068684/8491510 Andreas Engedal explained in his answer how to use SharedPreferences with Fragment in Android.